# Ionic Alert: Wait until button is pressed

Tags: ionic-framework, promise, alert

I have a class `Action` with it's method `do()` wherein the **IonicAlert** is called.
What I want to do now is, that I call something like
`Action.do().then( () => { /* do domething */ } );`
but only after **OK** was clicked on the alert.

```
do(): Promise<boolean> {

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: () => {
          alert.dismiss().then( () => { /* do something */ });
          return false;
        }
      }]
    });

    alert.present();
    return null;
  }
}
```

I added `return null;` only to get no error, but of course it's not working.
Any idea, how to solve this? Thanks

PS: I also posted it to the ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-alert-wait-until-button-is-pressed/67448

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of this site: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/promise.html

```
do(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        buttons: [{
          text: 'OK',
          handler: () => {
            alert.dismiss().then(() => { resolve(true); });
            return false;
          }
        }]
      });

      alert.present();

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here a version who can return true or false :

```
 showConfirm(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      const confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title : 'Are you sure ?',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Yes',
            handler:_=> resolve(true)
          },
          {
            text: 'No',
            handler:_=> resolve(false)
          }
        ]
      }).present();
    })
  }
```

To call the promise :

```
this.showConfirm().then((result) => {
        if(result){
          // do something
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
handler: () => {
           console.log(this.viewCtrl.dismiss());
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

That code didn't work for me in Ionic4.  This did:

```
presentAlert():Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ctl = this.alertController;
    let alert:any = this.alertController.create({
      buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: () => {
          ctl.dismiss().then(() => { resolve(true); });
          return false;
        }
      }]
    }).then((dlg) => dlg.present());
  });
}
```